# XML namespaces and the default namespace

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

I received an XML document that causes me some headaches.

It looks like this here:

```
<ns1:ObjectInfo xmlns:ns1="urn:package:ObjectInfo" xmlns="package:ObjectInfo">
...
    <Object Id="12345">
        <ns1:ObjectInfo xmlns="urn:package:ObjectInfo">
        </ns1:ObjectInfo>
    </Object>
...
</ns1:ObjectInfo>
```

I am no XML expert, but from what I know this "xmlns="package:ObjectInfo" defines the default namespace, right?

Is it really common practice to first explicitly define a namespace (ns1:ObjectInfo xmlns:ns1="urn:package:ObjectInfo") and than also define a default namespace (xmlns="package:ObjectInfo") ?

From what I *think* might cause the problems is that the default namespace has a typo (is: xmlns="package:ObjectInfo", but should be: "**urn**:package:ObjectInfo") - which makes me think: to which namespace does the ObjectInfo element in Object belong/refer to?

Comment: It's certainly common to define several namespace aliases and also define a default namespace. The commonality between the two namespace URIs is unusual here though.

Comment: What kind of document is that? A Google for "urn:package:ObjectInfo" only finds this question!

Answer (score 1):

> which makes me think: to which namespace does the ObjectInfo element in Object belong/refer to?

ObjectInfo certainly belongs to namespace ns1. All the sub elements of ObjectInfo element in Object element with "no namespace prefix" should fall under default namespace xmlns="urn:package:ObjectInfo"

I'm not sure if there is a typo. But, Object element in  falls under top-level default namespace xmlns="package:ObjectInfo"

Comment: I agree. Maybe that first one should be `xmlns="urn:package:ObjectInfo"`

Comment: @John Yes, if the first one is like you said, then the second one is redundant